# Pandas ValueError: Usecols do not match names

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I get a ValueError when I try to read the specific column of a file while using pd.read_csv(). When I read the file without usecols, everything works fine.

I recreated the problem in a simplified manner:

```
test_column = "Test Column"
data = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], columns=[test_column])

data.to_csv("test_data.csv", decimal=",", sep=";")

data_read = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv", decimal=",", sep=";", usecols=test_column)
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html usecolslist-like or callable, optional   you are passing a string not a list try: `data_read = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv", decimal=",", sep=";", usecols=[test_column])`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation, the `usecols` parameter is expecting either a list-like object or a callable function. I think the specific error you're getting is because `read_csv` is interpreting the value you passed to it as a list of characters, none of which match the column names in the file.

So even though you only have one column name, you still need to pass it as a list, similar to when you created the dataframe.

```
data_read = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv", decimal=",", sep=";", usecols=[test_column])
```